# Create app database with data in table

Tags: android, mysql, sql, database

Simply what I want is when android application is launched for the first time to create database and have standard values in it.

I am successfully initiating `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` and creating a table when application is opened first time. Let's say there will be EUR and USD lines in DB. I want EUR to have already value 100 and USD value 0.

What would be simplest solution for populating database table when table is created/first time application is launched(database table will be created anyway only one time when first time launching app)?

I have read about creating database file in assets folder and then just copying it, creating flag in SharedPreferences to know when application is launched for a first time and then create and populated database or just create method in main onCreate() that check database and fills it if it's empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be start:

```
void createdDatabase() {
    String databasePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + File.separator + "database.db";
    SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(databasePath, null, null);

    String sqlCreateMessages = "CREATE TABLE currencies (\n" +
        " id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,\n" +
        " name text NOT NULL,\n" +
        " value text NOT NULL\n" +
        ")";
    database.execSQL(sqlCreateMessages);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("name", "EUR");
    values.put("value", "100");
    database.insert("currencies", null, values);
    values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("name", "USD");
    values.put("value", "0");
    database.insert("currencies", null, values);
}
```